# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Digest method not supported in Featherjs

Tags: reactjs

When creating a user locally on featherjs, I came across this error:

***app.js:117 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Digest method not supported***

This is the code that calls a function when the user clicks on the submit after the input fields are filled up:

```
addEventListener('#signup', 'click', async () => {
    const credentials = getCredentials();
    
    await client.service('users').create(credentials);

});
```

This is the code creates the user and calls the user:

```
const getCredentials = () => {
    const user = {
        email: document.querySelector('[name="email"]').value,
        password: document.querySelector('[name="password"]').value
    };

    return user;
}
```

This is the HTML portion of the code:

```
const loginHTML = `
<main class="login container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-6-tablet push-3-tablet text-center heading" >
        <h1 class="font-100">Log in or signup</h1>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-6-tablet push-3-tablet col-4-desktop push-4-desktop">
        <form class="form">

        <fieldset>
        <input class="block" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" >
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
        <input class="block" type="password " name="password" placeholder="password" >
        </fieldset>

        <button type="button" id="login" class="button button-primary block signup">
        Log in
        </button>

        <button type="button" id="signup" class="button button-primary block signup">
        Sign up and log in
        </button>

        <a class="button button-primary block" href="/oauth/github">
        Login with Github
        </a>


        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    `;
```

This is the login portion of the code:

```
const login = async (credentials) => {
    try  {
        if(!credentials){

            await client.reAuthenticate();
        } else {
            
            await client.authenticate({
                
                strategy: 'local',
                ...credentials,
            });

        }
        console.log('signup / login success! go to chat window...')
        } catch (error){

            showLogin(error);

    }
};
```

Comment: This is crypto error, maybe your username or password is null ! share your full source or any sample on codesandbox

Comment: greetings I've added more of the code